# How to do the final steps of the k-means algorithm

Tags: algorithm, k-means

I’m having a problem with my program. I am trying to implement k-means (manually) by clustering a set of RGB values to 3 clusters. I don’t need help with coding just with understanding. So far I have done this:

1. Created 3 cluster objects, each with a mean and an array to hold that clusters members.
2. Imported the text file and saved the RGB values in an array.
3. Looped the array and for each RGB value stored, calculated the mean with the closest distance using Euclidian distance.
4. Added each RGB value to the array of the cluster with the closest mean.

I have done research and I can’t seem to understand the next step. Research has suggested:

In each cluster, add all of the RGB values together divide them by the number of values in that cluster, then update the mean with that value or;

Find the average distance between all RGB values and the mean, then update the mean with that value or;

Update the mean each time you add a RGB to the cluster…..

I just can’t seem to understand the last steps, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a per-cluster array, recompute the "cluster center" as the average of the items in that cluster.  Then, reassign every item to the appropriate cluster (the one whose "center" it's closest to after the recomputation).  You're done when no item changes cluster (it's theoretically possible to end up in a situation where one item keeps flipping between two clusters, with generalized distance measures -- this can be detected to stop the loop anyway -- but I don't think it can happen with Euclidean distances).

IOW, that would be the first one of your three alternatives.  I'm not even sure what you mean by the second alternative; the third one would likely not be stable, and depend on the arbitrary order of items, so I feel strongly against it.

Comment: So would be fair to say: compute the new mean of each cluster by adding up the RGB values than dividing by the number of how many they are. Clear all of the cluster member arrays and repeat steps 4, 5 and this step until the means can no longer be updated?

Comment: @user3178205, yep, a fair summary.  Keeping track of cluster-assignment switches is, IMHO, a better mind-set because, just in case more general distance measures are in use, it can alert you to the anomaly of single items flipping between clusters ("I'm not really sure how it goes" -- what characteristics of a distance measure can allow such anomalies -- but "I knew it complete // when I wore a younger man's clothes" and computed K-means clustering on a mainframe 30+ years ago... had to learn it after eating a huge amount of CPU time by **not** checking for the anomaly!-).